# SSL error has occured and a secure connection to the server cannot be made IOS 13.3.1

Tags: ios, wordpress, ssl

I am getting an SSL error only when using while using WordPress for IOS I cannot view nor connect to my wordpress site from my IOS devices. After over a week of troubleshooting with my host and wordpress for ios the issues still persist and no one seem to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

iOS has new TLS restrictions as of iOS 13. I created a package written in Obj-C to handle sockets, and I also included a lot of good info in the `readme` about how to correctly configure certificates given the new restrictions.

https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets/tree/master